# How to get variables from block with id type

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, swizzling

I have block declaration

```
typedef void (^ServerResponse)(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error);
```

I have variable of type

```
id myObj;
```

which contains that block inside.
The question is how to get access to variables from block declaration:
data, response and error via pointer on it of id type.

I'm using such a construction to swizzle NSURLSession method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the only one way is to declare ServerResponse variable locally and pass this new ServerResponse to original Swizzling call. Your new block should call the old block to keep logic solid.

Comment: Sounds reasonable